# doctrine2 symfony2.1 entity all fields in $showMapper?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony-2.1

I don't know if this is possible or not or how to do this

Table A
id
name
feature_id
...

Table B
id_feature
label
url
description
...

I got 2 entity, i do a @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="tableB")

In my $showmapper i got result with label, but not with url, description

Why ?

how to do that in my entity ?

Thanks
Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved...

i do like this

```
->add('parent1', 'entity', array('label' => 'region', 'property_path' => 'appellation.parent.parent', 'class' => 'Application\Ghv\AdministrationBundle\Entity\Regions'))
```

i can acces my sub property like this